# Angular 6 + Nginx + Docker + Kubernetes: How to configure environment variables for different environments

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, angular6

I have an Angular 6 application that I'm required to deploy onto a Kubernetes cluster as a Docker container (Nginx Base Image).

**Question**: How do I accommodate using the same Docker image that's built once, but to be able to run in dev & prod and point to different API_URL?

My **Environment Files**:

*environment.ts*

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL: 'https://dev-server.domain.com'
};
```

*environment.prod.ts*

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  API_URL: 'https://prod-server.domain.com'
};
```

My **nginx.conf**

```
worker_processes 1;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;

        root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        gzip on;
        gzip_min_length 1000;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

My **Dockerfile**:

```
# base image
FROM nginx:alpine

# private and public mapping
EXPOSE 80

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY dist/my_project .
```

At this point, I build my project on my local machine and optimize it for production:

```
ng build --prod --build-optimizer
```

So, at this point my file structure looks like the following:

```
root
    |--Dockerfile
    |--nginx.conf
    |--angular.json
    |--dist
       |--my_project
          |--styles.3ed0e5393a1386f6fc48.css
          |--runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js
          |--polyfills.2f5aa8fb3d2aea854d83.js
          |--main.2b3e9b16d82428586ae5.js
          |--index.html
          |--favicon.ico
          |--3rdpartylicenses.txt
          |--assets
```

Now, I'm ready to create the docker image:

```
docker build -t my_application_image .
```

Then, I push the image to the Docker registry, and then used in Kubernetes.

Now that you know my setup, can you suggest how I can modify this such that different environment files can be used for dev & prod?

Answer (score 3):

One of the ways to solve it would be to add an entrypoint script to your docker image and a default prod env. The use only one environment.ts with something like :

```
export const environment = {
  production: {{production}},
  API_URL: '{{api_url}}'
};
```

Dockerfile with

```
ENV PRODUCTION=true API_URL=https://prod-server.domain.com
ADD entrypoint.sh /entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT /entrypoint.sh
```

and finally entrypoint it self

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i "s/{{production}}/${PRODUCTION}/g" environment.ts
sed -i "s/{{api_url}}/${API_URL}/g" environment.ts
exec $@
```

Comment: Thanks Radek. Since the Docker image is created once and reused in other environments, we don't have the environment.ts file anymore. Hence, this will not work for me.

Comment: However, this does give me an idea. I could use your 'sed' commands to modify the main.2b3e9b16d82428586ae5.js file which contains the URLs.

This is an odd work around at best. But, will work for now.

Thanks for the tip.